# AngularJS project not communication with WebAPI project

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, iis-7

I am new to AngularJS and WebAPI.  I have two Visual Studio 2015 projects, EventViewer (AngularJS) and AppData (WebAPI), and have configured IIS Express 7 to host the website. I have the path to the AngularJS project as the path for the website, and that is working fine. For the AppData project (WebAPI), I added an application to the website.  As a path for the website application, *I am using the physical path to the folder housing the WebAPI project.*  Is that correct? Is it sufficient to enable the angular and webAPI apps to talk to each other? The AngularJS app doesn't seem to be communicating with the WebAPI app. When I browse the website from IIS, I get the correct pages but no data.  What am I missing?  Any help will be appreciated.

AngularJS controller:

```
'use strict';

    eventsApp.controller('EventListController',
        function EventListController($scope, eventData) {
            $scope.events = eventData.getAllEvents();
        });
```

AngularJS service:

```
eventsApp.factory('eventData', function ($resource) {
    var resource = $resource('/data/event/:id', { id: '@id' }, { "getAll": { method: "GET", isArray: true, params: { something: "foo" } } });
    return {
        getAllEvents: function () {
            return resource.query();
        }
 };
});
```

WebAPI controller:

```
namespace AppData.Controllers
{
    public class EventController : ApiController
    {
        public JToken Get(string id = null)
        {
            if (id == null)
                return GetAllJsonEventsAsArray();
            return GetSingleJsonFile(id);
        }

        private static JToken GetSingleJsonFile(string id)
        {
            var path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/");
            return JObject.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path + "../app/data/event/" + id + ".json"));
        }

        public void Post(string id, JObject eventData)
        {
            var path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/");
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + "../app/data/event/" + id + ".json", eventData.ToString(Formatting.None));
        }

        private JArray GetAllJsonEventsAsArray()
        {
            var path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/");
            var contents = "";
            foreach (var file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path + "../app/data/event/"))
            {
                contents += System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file) + ",";
            }
            return JArray.Parse("[" + contents.Substring(0, contents.Length - 1) + "]");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, F12 in browser.

1. try to **console.log** for $scope.events = eventData.getAllEvents();
2. check also for **CORS** issue in BackEnd (Web API)

   to fix, its like this code : on Startup.cs

   > app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

Good Luck :)